# Why does this happen after setting "max-height:0" for CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x751cqsz/

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "nav.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class = "navigationBar">
    <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/nfbKl0W.png" class = "menuIcon">
    <ul class = "linkBar">

      <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Media</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Miscellaneous</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script>

    $('.menuIcon').on('click', function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');

body
{
  background-color: #598392;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
}

.menuIcon
{
  padding:20px;
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.navigationBar
{
  background-color: #124559;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.navigationBar li
{
  padding:20px;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none;

}

a
{
  color: #EFF6E0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
  color: #AEC3B0;
}
nav ul
{

  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.show
{
  display:block;
  transition: fadeIn 2s
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
  .menuIcon
  {
    display:block;
  }
  .navigationBar li
  {
    display:block;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul
  {
    max-height:0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
  nav ul
  {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Basically, [here's my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQGBB.png)

I want to hide the entire navigation bar, and when the user clicks the menu icon, I want an animation to occur between the max-height. So it will go from max-height: 0 to max-height: 50 for example and it will be a smooth transition to show the navbar.

But why is the "Home" peeking a little bit?

Comment: It's your `padding: 20px`.

Answer (score 2):

A `ul` element will most likely have some default `margin`, which is not considered part of the `height` and which will remain visible / occupy space when `height` is 0. Add `margin: 0` to the `ul` to avoid this.

Comment: I added margin: 0 and the same thing happened.

Comment: Then you have to explain your problem better - it's not clear from your code in the question and not clear from looking at the fiddle, where the menu icon isn't even visible.

Comment: You need to resize the jsfiddle window to see it, but I think the person above found the problem, it was padding: 20px in the .navigationbar li element

Answer (score 1):

Could you change `max-height: 0` to `display: none`? When you're using max-height you're adjusting the element's height. When you're using slideToggle you're adjusting it's display. I'm also not seeing "peeking", but I do see your home link showing by default on a mobile sized view.

Comment: Animations on height / display don't work with display none, which is almost certainly why `max-height` was used.

Comment: As he is using `slideToggle` to perform the animation, `display: none` should be the right answer.